"Lars doesn't like Facebook but Emma does (so)." — Can I use "so" here? If not, then why not?
I'm interested in what verbs can be replaced with "do so" and what verbs can't.

two examples from ell.stackexchange.com:
(1a) -I noticed a crack in the wall. -I did too. — (correct) ("did" is an auxiliary here)
(1b) -I noticed a crack in the wall. -I did so too. — (correct) (sounds formal) ("did" is a lexical verb here) ("did so" means "noticed a crack")
That means, we can replace "notice + object" with "do so".

the textbook "Advanced Grammar In Use", third edition, Hewings Martin, page 126:
(2a) Lars doesn't like Facebook but Emma does. — (correct) ("does" is an auxiliary here)
my variant:
(2b) Lars doesn't like Facebook but Emma does so. — Is this correct?
Can "like + object" be replaced with "do so"?
If not, then why not?

Update:
I asked this question because the translation of (1b) into my native language sounds just as odd as the translation of (2b). That's why I don't understand why native English speakers consider (2b) odd but at the same time consider (1b) acceptable.

so can't be used there. Native speakers don't do so.

Imagine a medical questionnaire asking whether you are able to perform certain acts and activities.  Can you climb the stairs?  Can you bend over and tie your shoes?  Can you put on your shirt without assistance?  *Can you like Facebook?

There is also the negative to consider in addition to whether the verb's action can be performed.

Lars sings. Emma does too.    Lars doesn't sing but Emma does.  Lars sings Broadway tunes. Emma does (so) too.

can you [verb] is a decent test of whether so will work with a given verb  anaphorically but only when the meaning is "are you able to [verb]" (is one able to, is a person able to perform that action, is that action performable) not "is it possible to [verb]"

Lars thinks it's strange. *Emma does so too.   We don't perform thinking.  Lars feels ill. *Emma does so too.

@TimR Thanks for participating. I added an update to the original post.

This question is similar to: What verb phrases can I replace with "do it" or "do that"? E.g.: "-I noticed a small crack in the wall. -I did it too / I did that too." — Is this OK?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You have already asked this question in another form (see above). An auxiliary short answer to a lexical verb cannot take an object.

@Lambie What you put to me makes sense only in your own world which apparently you like very much. But to me, the difference between the original question and the question you quoted is so obvious that I don't think it's worth explaining.

Question: Lars doesn't like Facebook but Emma does so. — Is this correct?=NO, because "like" is a lexical verb and the so in "does so" is a substitute for the  preceding clause. Merriam Webster: The meaning of SO is in a manner or way indicated or suggested —often used as a substitute for a preceding clause

I saw | noticed | discovered | found a crack in the wall.  -- I did too.  did so too doesn't work there.

In example 2, the important thing is that the auxiliary "doesn't" is contrasted with "does" and vice versa. "A doesn't ski", "B does", "A doesn't like cheese", "B does", and with emphatic "do", "A does like cheese", "B doesn't", etc.

@StuartF From your comment I infer that "Lars didn't notice a crack in the wall but Emma did so" is incorrect to you, right? Thanks.
